# name 'serializer' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build an API on Django REST framework but when I try to use the POST method I get this error:

```
name 'serializer' is not defined
```

This is the API view:

```
class apiOverview(APIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.EmailsSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        an_apiview = [


        ]
        return Response({'message':'Hello!', 'an_apiview': an_apiview})


    def post(self, request):
        serializer_class = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            url = serializer.validated_data.get('url')
            message = f'The url is {url}'
            return Response({'message': message})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The error is in this line particularly when trying to validate:

```
  if serializer.is_valid():
            url = serializer.validated_data.get('url')
            message = f'The url is {url}'
            return Response({'message': message})
```

All apps are correctly installed.

Comment: `serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `post` method you use the `serializer` often, but that variable does not exist, nor did you import something with the name `serializer`.

Very likely you construct the serializer through the `serializer_class`, you thus fix this with:

```
def post(self, request):
    #    ↓  serializer instead of serializer_class
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        url = serializer.validated_data.get('url')
        message = f'The url is {url}'
        return Response({'message': message})
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```